# Can VB have "isolated contexts" like you can in C#?

Tags: vb.net, scope

I put "isolated context" in quotes because I don't know what else you would call it.  Basically, in C#, you can do this:

```
{ int i = 0; }
{ int i = 1; }
```

The curly braces create an isolated context which allows you to declare two variables with the same name in the same method or property logic.  Is this possible in VB.NET?  Also, what do you call this aside from an isolated context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a code block in VB.NET that doesn't belong to a control flow construction.

You can, however, simulate it:

```
If True Then
  Dim i As Integer = 0
End If

If True Then
  Dim i As Integer = 1
End If
```

As for the term, I would say it's **scope**.